# How can I extract a password protected .zip file from within my PHP application?

Tags: php, encryption, zip

How can I extract a password protected `.zip` file from within my PHP application?

Answer (score 8):

Since PHP 5.6.0 you can use the class [ZipArchive](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). Encrypted files can be decrypted by setting a password with the [setPassword()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) method.

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('file.zip') === true) {
    $zip->setPassword('MyPassword');
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this (assuming your server has the "right" os :-))

```
echo shell_exec('unzip -P password file.zip');
```

Comment: And how is this PHP? The questing clearly states the asker wants to extract a password protected zip file __using__ PHP. Not some platform-specific tool.

Comment: You're not using PHP __at all__, your executing environment is PHP.

Comment: `unzip` might be platform-specific, but `7-Zip` isn't. You can install it and use `7za` on Linux, Windows, and Mac OS with basically identical CLI arguments.

Comment: With this definition you do not use php to save something to a mysql db if you use mysql_query neither, because the db server is executing the insertion and not php

Comment: @nightcracker, PHP's extensions are also platform-specific. They're written in C/C++, and compile to `.so` file on Linux and to `.dll`s on Windows. They might *ship* with PHP, but that doesn't mean that they're written *in* PHP.

Comment: I thought I'd chime in and mention that there doesn't appear to be any support in the zip extension for archives that are password protected. @strauberry's answer seems to be the way to go.

Comment: On the topic of portability, you could abstract the command to run differently depending on platform. Unzip should work fine on Linux and Mac regardless.

Comment: I seldom find myself defending PHP, but it's worth noting that it is a server-side scripting language, and your script will probably live out its life on the first server it's deployed on. Portability isn't that big a concern.

Comment: linux +[cpanel][litespeed webserver]

Comment: Ok and what's the error or the output??? unzip is installed (per default) on linux so there must be some other issues but without an error message no one can help you!

Comment: Note that this will happily report the supplied password to other users on the system via `ps auxw` or `top` or similar commands, unless a tool such as [SElinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/), or grsecurity are installed and configured to prevent it.