# Opening and creating password protected zip files with PHP

Tags: php, zip, password-protection

I have found the following two commands to respecively create and open password protected zip files. I was however wondering if it's possible to do this in pure PHP

```
echo system('zip -P password file.zip file.txt');  
echo shell_exec('unzip -P password file.zip');
```

Comment: I assume you already know about PHP's Zip extensions http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php, but I don't think it supports password protected archives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract a password protected .zip file from within my PHP application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654115/how-can-i-extract-a-password-protected-zip-file-from-within-my-php-application)

Comment: Accepted answer is not correct. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create simple file zip using some libraries (as [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip)) but you can't create zip with the password.

Comment: Can *PclZip* open password protected ones?

Comment: @hakre First of all thanks for edit my answer. Anyway, as I know, it can't do.

Answer (score 5):

It was not possible do do below **PHP5.6.0**. But in a new **PHP5.6.x** version developers added this [functionality](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php). So no need for a scary `system` or `shell_exec` (which can lead to security vulnerability).

So right now you can do something like this:

```
ZipArchive::setPassword($password)
```

Comment: Why this isn't the accepted answer? Best regards, you saved my day :) +1

Comment: Reading? yes, adding files? not yet from my point of view:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67590&thanks=4

Comment: ZipArchive::setPassword($password) only works for reading not creating zip archives:     
Note:

    This function only sets the password to be used to decompress the archive; it does not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php

Answer (score 3):

No, [PHP's ZIP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) has no support for passwords. You might look for another ZIP library that supports it and has PHP language bindings.

I don't know any from the top of my head that supports it for creating *and* opening.

Comment: Do you know of any libraries that either open or create?

Comment: Well same for or. You might be able to search for one in the internet, I mean you specifically know what you're looking for. You can leave that as an answer later and accept it.