# Creating a Password Protected Zip File using PHP in Windows

Tags: php, windows, zip, password-protection

I am creating a zip file of a given file in PHP. Following is the function

```
function create_zip($file, $file_name) 
{   
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip_name = $file_name. ".zip"; // Zip name
    $zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));
    } else {
        return "file does not exist";
    }
    $zip->close();

    return $zip_name;   
}
```

I want to add password protection for the Zip files. I have found following code to create a password protected zip file

```
system('zip -P password file.zip file.txt');
```

But it is not working properly. Can you please Guide me How can I add the Password protection on the Zip file?

Comment: what do you mean by not working properly ?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to password protect an existing zip file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening and creating password protected zip files with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712960/opening-and-creating-password-protected-zip-files-with-php)

Comment: It can't be done ... yet.

Comment: Nothing is done with this command

Comment: neither any error Nor the File created

Comment: I'm guessing you have to put the full path to the files.

Comment: The parameter $file is coming along with the File path

Comment: @DainisAbols you already can do this. With new `php5.6`. Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23164412/1090562

Comment: True: `since 11 Apr 2014 . new method ZipArchive::setPassword($password). (Pierre)`. Thanks for the info @SalvadorDali

Comment: @DainisAbols you are free to accept/upvote my answer :-). And you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

PHP Zip - http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php - doesn't support password protected zip files, you will need do it via command line.

To password protect a file, you need to use `zip` command line, make sure that the `zip` command line program is present, it is not installed by default on many systems.

Comment: run in the command prompt/terminal `zip` and see if it returns something

Comment: C:\>zip
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ha you didn't say it was on Windows :) do you have 7z installed by any chance?

Comment: Try to run: `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe`

Answer (score 2):

In new **PHP 5.6** ([currently in beta](http://www.php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-04-11-1)) you can use your [ZipArchive](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-functions.php) to create password protected archives. All you need is to add this code `ZipArchive::setPassword($password)`

Edit: Apparently it only [supports decryption](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php#115803), not encryption yet.

Comment: how to open zip file with password? any idea?

Comment: setPassword is available since 5.6 but does currently nothing at all. So the archive wont be protected! Keep that in mind.

Comment: @user426486 wow, did no know that. Based on documentation it should be adding password. Have you thought about posting a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug, setPassword sets the password used to OPEN password protected archives. It doesn't create a password protected zip.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but anyone struggling with adding a password to an archive in windows environment, I solved this using winrar command line and `exec` in PHP.

Download winrar from http://www.rarlab.com/ and include the WinRAR.exe in your PHP script directory, or call it from the right directory in your `exec` command.

`exec("winrar a -p[password] [archive name] [file or folders to include]");`

`winrar` in the above example refers to winrar.exe in the same directory as your script. If winrar.exe is NOT in the same directory as your script, you can simply include the path:

`exec("C:\Program Files\Winrar...`

So, for example:
`exec("winrar a -ppassword archive.zip file.txt");`

Will result in an archive named "archive.zip" being created with "file.txt" inside, and a password of "password".

For more information on winrar command line: http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/

Comment: 7-zip would be a much better choice because "7-Zip is open source software. Most of the source code is under the GNU LGPL license."

Comment: I'm taking files from an encrypted zip file, modifying them in memory, then adding them to an archive. I don't want them to ever show up on disk in an unencrypted form. I don't see any way, with either with 7Z or winrar to do an 'in place' update of files in an archive to password protect them if those files don't exist on disk outside the archive. Seems like I'm going to have to abandon the idea of relying on the archiver's encryption capabilities and instead encrypt the files myself before adding them to the archive, and decrypt them msyelf after I pull them out into memory.