# How To make Script To Download videos from a remote server and add them to a password protected .zip

Tags: php, video, zip

On of my friend of friend has a high speed unlimited internet.
 I want him to download some videos for me like 2-3 GB in size. 
I don't want him to know what I want to download. 
So I think to make a php script which can download videos from a remote server or from flash players then store it on the server and add all the videos to a .zip file with a unbreakable password or encryption so he can't know what is inside the zip(file Names).
Then rename the file from .zip to something like .parts1 for more security but I don't know how to code it please help me geniuses.

Comment: PHP does not support password protected ZIP files, you would have to do it via the command line. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883532/creating-a-password-protected-zip-file-using-php-in-windows for more details

Comment: @mic But I am using a linux server from web hosting site. how can I execute a command.

Comment: You need to checkout http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php, that will show you how to execute CLI commands from your application. You might not be able to do it with a shared hosting package because they may block access to certain functionality. If you are not sure how to do some of these things it because they are quite complicated (hence why no one else is commenting) and i would suggest searching google (or other) to learn to walk before you run.

Comment: @mic For Your help I think you are only genius here.