# how to prevent extracting a php file from zip

Tags: php, unzip

i am using this piece of code to unzip a .zip file

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
   $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
   $zip->close();
   echo 'ok';
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}
```

Lets say: there is a .php file in the .zip and i do not want a .php file to be extracted. How can i prevent that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening and creating password protected zip files with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712960/opening-and-creating-password-protected-zip-files-with-php)

Comment: @Parixit How is this duplicated ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I think this is regarding secure zip as he asks not to extract "php" file

Comment: @Parixit The OP wants to filter the extraction of php files from a zip file, that's it.

Comment: Why don't you try to prevent somebody from running the script? Maybe a .htaccess inside your "uploaded goodies" folder that redirects requests to a single php script which reads the url for the file and return it's contents with `Content-Disposition: Attachment`? That way they would always download, no matter the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this for `PHP >= 5.5`:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {

 for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
     if( pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i)['extension'] != "php")){
        $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', $zip->getNameIndex($i));
     }
}
   $zip->close();
}
```

Or this for `PHP < 5.5`:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {

 for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
     $path_info = pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i));
     $ext = $path_info['extension'];
     if( $ext != "php")){
        $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', $zip->getNameIndex($i));
     }
}
   $zip->close();
}
```

---

The only difference between the two is the `pathinfo` function. Both will loop all files inside the zip file and, if the file extension **isn't** `php`, extracts it to `/my/destination/dir/`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$zip= new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE){
 for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
  $filename = pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i));
  $fileinfo = $filename['extension'];
  if($fileinfo!="php"){
    $zip->extractTo('extract/',$zip->getNameIndex($i));
  }
  $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Please do not limit your answers to code snippets only. Adding an explanation will make it more readable.

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and mine? I really don't care if you copied my answer but it isn't a good practice.